# What is the difference between LBP and LBPV?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

if the  Local binary pattern is efficient approach why came Local binary pattern variance.i need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local binary pattern (LBP) is an efficient approach for texture classification and is categorized as a local invariant feature extraction approach.

However, it has the disadvantage of losing a lot of global spatial information.  On the other hand, global rotation invariant feature loses local texture information.

So, a hybrid approach LBP variance is proposed to characterize the local contrast information into a 1D LBP histogram and has the advantage of not requiring any quantization and is totally training free; trading off some algorithm efficiency.

Accuracy wise, LBP variance can be up to 10% more accurate.

An interesting implementation here for coin identification shows some interesting results - http://www.academia.edu/4061385/Implementation_of_Coin_Recognition_by_Extracting_the_local_texture_features_with_Gabor_Wavelet_and_LBP

Comment: what does sentence mean" totally training free"?